# Last unique row

Tags: birt

This problem relates to report design in BIRT.

Due to limitations in the data source, I have a data set with the following rows:

```
Id Name   Class
---------------
1  Name1  Foo
2  Name1  Bar
3  Name2  Fizz
4  Name2  Buzz
5  Name3  Baz
```

Duplicates of the name column should be suppressed, and only the last result should be displayed:

```
Id Name   Class
---------------
2  Name1  Bar
4  Name2  Buzz
5  Name3  Baz
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming your data is in ID order)

1. Insert a Group in your BIRT report, on name.
2. Copy the detail row items into the new group footer.
3. Delete the detail row and new group header row.

The output from the report should match your requirements.